# shiny: plotting selected columns from dataset to graphs

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Just discovering shiny apps but this is driving me insane.......I have looked at numerous examples of server.R and ui.R code and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Apologies in advance if it's something very basic..........

Taking the iris dataset as an example, I want to plot one column against another, something simple using qplot or preferably ggplot

However, using qplot I get this:
[image: qplot output]

and using ggplot2, I get the error:
[image: ggplot output]

I don't think I need the reactive function as I'm not subsetting the dataset, just extracting columns to plot.

server.R code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyapps)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    output$text1 <- renderText({input$id1})

    output$text2 <- renderText({input$select1})

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
            g <- qplot(Sepal.Length, input$select1, data = iris)
            print(g)
    })
```

})

or using ggplot function to replace the qplot call

```
            g <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = input$select1)) 
            g <- g + geom_line(col = "green", lwd =1) + 
                    labs(x = "Date", y = "Ranking") + 
                    theme_bw() + scale_y_reverse()
```

ui.R code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyapps)
data(iris)
opts <- unique(colnames(iris))
opts <- opts[-1] ## want to keep Sepal.Length as the x values

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('test with iris database'),
    sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(inputId = "select1", label = "select", 
                        choices = opts),
            textInput(inputId = "id1", label = "Input Text", "")
    ),
    mainPanel(
            p('Output text1'),
            textOutput('text1'),
            textOutput('text2'),
            plotOutput('plot1')
    )
))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `aes` statement to `aes_string` and make `x` a string.  This should fix the problem.

```
g <- ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = "Sepal.Length", y = input$select1)) 
g <- g + geom_line(col = "green", lwd =1) +
     labs(x = "Date", y = "Ranking") + 
     theme_bw() + scale_y_reverse()
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, that solves my problem. I'm assuming that aes_string is needed as the return of input$select1 is a character string? I had tried defining input$select1 as a non-character using as.name, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: @laoisman, truthfully I am not completely certain what the internals are.  This answer is from experience and what the documentation has shown me.  If you are curious, I suggest contacting the maintainer of the Shiny package.  Sorry I couldn't answer your followup question.